# How do I find out what blocking call is stopping tasks from being processed?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, azure-web-app-service, blocking

I have a problem with an ASP.NET-Core Webapplication running as an Appservice on Azure. We are experiencing frequent spikes in Response-time due to something blocking a thread-worker (at least thats what we think). We do have a couple of Application-Insights profiler traces of requests that should only (and usually do) take 10ths of milliseconds taking more than a minute to complete. On examination it is always the same problem:

[image: 19 Seconds await]

**Is there any way to see what the thread that is supposed to be processing the awaited task is currently working/waiting on?**

Since this looks like a blocking problem, I suspected some blocking calls in the codebase that block threads that are not using ConfigueAwait(false) and then must wait for the blocking call to complete. I have looked through the code and a lot of traces, but I can't seem to find anything that would explain such horrendous await times. The only things I found were waiting times in Expression-Compilation (EF-Core):

[image: Why does it need to wait 7 seconds to compile an expression?]

But I somehow doubt this is the issue.

**I would however like to know what exactly the thread here is waiting on.**

TLDR: I want to find the culprit that blocks the awaited Task from being processed

Comment: First of all, if you are using asp.net core, then ConfigureAwait(false) won't do anything useful (because asp.net core doesn't run in synchronizationcontext). That's definitely not a problem. Secondly, you profiled EF Core expression compilation as bottleneck. Why do you doubt this profiling? To put it differently: why do you think that expression compilation is (1) a fast process and (2) that EF can always do it efficiently? I can assure you, that if query is complicated enough it will take a looooong time. Lots of people have performance issues with EF (regardless of i/o), you can google it.

Comment: @freakish So you mean it could be an issue where, due to a large number of requests, the amount of queries suddenly spikes and the expression-compiler cant keep up with the number of requests, making queries wait for other compilations to complete first?
Is Expression-Compilation or its code-emmiting blocking?

Comment: I don't really know details of the compilation process. But EF is known to do many slow thing behind the scenes. It does some conversions that are very slow, it does entity tracking which is also slow, and many many more. The bigger models and queries you have, the slower it is. And it is in the order of seconds. Throw a lock on top of that, and concurrency is killed. One of the reason I no longer use EF. Plus I don't know how exactly you use EF, so its hard to really say what is going on. But I would trust that profiling, especially if you didn't find anything else.

Comment: A full memory dump should be able to tell you much more than what Application Insights showed, if you can find someone to analyze that for you.